# Expected time to the next bus arrival

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Buses arrive at a bus stop either $5$ mins or $10$ minutes apart from each other. 
The interarrival intervals $5$ and $10$ are equally likely but otherwise they may follow in any order.

A person shows up at the bus stop at a random time.

What is the expected time to the next bus arrival?

I think the answer should be $$\frac{2}{3} \cdot 5 + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 2.5$$ but I want to be sure.

Why do I think this is the answer? Because the person who shows up at the bus stop has $2/3$ probability of falling into a $10$ min interval, and in that case the expected time to the next arrival would be the average of the time to the next arrival which is $10/2 = 5$ (if we assume the person show up time is uniformly distributed over the $10$ min interval). Then I apply the same logic to the $5$ min intervals, and finally I use the total expectation theorem.

Is this way of thinking correct? 
I just want to be sure. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.

Let the random variable $A$ be $1$ if we fall inside a 10 min interval, $A=0$  otherwise. You are right in assuming $P(A=1)=2/3$ (many fall into the trap of assuming $P(A=1)=1/2$).

Then, letting $T$ the time to the next bus arrival

$$E[T]=E[E[T|A]]= P(A=0)E[T|A=0]+P(A=1)E[T|A=1]=\frac13 \frac52 + \frac23 \frac{10}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for confirming. You meant A=0 otherwise.

Comment: Sure, fixed, thanks